# How to generate IDbSet instead of DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx-designer

I'm new to `C#` and  `EntityFramework` and I need to maintain an active software.
I needed to create a new table so I created it in the database and then updated my Model with EntityFramework.

Howewer, it looks like the previous developer had been writing code directly in generated code (The `Mode.Context.cs` class) and `EntityFramework` when updating the model is wiping it and rewritting it completly.

So I did a new partial class Model. It looks like this :

```
public partial class Model : DbContext, IModel
    {
        public void SomeRandomMethod();
    }
```

And the generated Model looks like this :

```
public partial class Model : DbContext
{
    public Model()
        : base("name=Model")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<RandomTable> ARandomTable { get; set; }
}
```

The problem, however, is that previously, the model was using `IDbSet` instead of `DbSet` and the interface `IModel` is asking for `IDbSet<RandomTable> ARandomTable`

What would be the proper way to deal with that ?

Comment: Update the code a little, this `IModel` can only be asking for SomeRandomMethod(). Be clear about what is your code, and why you need an I in  IDbSet.

Comment: If the generation tool is using T4 then just update the T4 model.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Thanks, managed to to it with templates. Just needed a hint to what to look at :)

Comment: Which gneration tool are you using? If T4 templates, then go the file and look at the line (CTRL + F) that set `IDbSet`. Save the file and regenerate the code.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the `Dbcontext` that represents your database has several `DbSet<TEntity>` properties, where every `DbSet` represents a table in your database.

All non-virtual properties of `TEntity` represent the columns in your table; the virtual properties of `TEntity` represent the relations between tables: one-to-many, many-to-many etc.

Every `DbSet<TEntity>` implements `IDbSet<TEntity>` so wherever your old `DbContext` used an `IDbSet`, you can give it the corresponding `DbSet` instead.

If I understand you correctly, your old `DbContext` had some properties that implemented `IDbSet<...>`, and method `SomeRandomMethod` used these properties.

```
class MyOldDbContext : DbContext
{
     public IDbSet<Aentity> Aentities {get; set;}
     public IDbSet<Bentity> BEntities {get; set;} 

     public void SomeRandomMethod()
     {   // this method uses the IdBsets AEntities and BEntities:
         IDbSet<AEntity> x = this.AEntities;
         IDbSet<BEntity> y = this.BEntities;
         ... // do something with x and y
     }
}
```

Now your new DbContext. If the DbSets have the same Entity types as the old ones, there is no problem:

```
class MyNewDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Aentity> Aentities {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Bentity> BEntities {get; set;} 

     public void SomeRandomMethod()
     {   // this method uses the DbSets AEntities and BEntities, which implement IDbSet
         IDbSet<AEntity> x = this.AEntities;
         IDbSet<BEntity> y = this.BEntities;
         ... // do something with x and y
     }
}
```

Note that AEntities/BEntities are now `DbSet<...>` instead of `IDbSet<...>`. Because every `DbSet<...>` implements `IDbSet<...>`, your problem is solved.

It is a bit more difficult if your new tables are different than your old ones. In that case you'll have to write adapter properties, that return the expected `IDbSet<...>`

```
class MyNewDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
     public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;} 

     public void SomeRandomMethod()
     {   // this method uses the IdBset of AEntities and BEntities:
         IDbSet<AEntity> x = this.AEntities;
         IDbSet<BEntity> y = this.BEntities;
         ... // do something with x and y
     }

     // for SomeRandomMethod we need properties AEntities and BEntities
     // use your new DbSets to mimic the old AEntities and BEntities
     private IDbSet<AEntity> AEntities => this.Teachers
          .Join(this.Students, ...)
          .Where(...)
          .Select(...);
      // similar for BEntities
}
```